# How to show all categories after customer account left navigation in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, layer

I want to show all categories after customer longed in. That means all categories are shows after **Customer Left Navigation**. I many times try it through difference way but I can't do this. Have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

At last resolved this, I found this solution just following few step.

**Step 1 :**

Create a block in **app/code/local/mage/customer/block/account/categories.php** and past code as

```
class Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Categories extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
}
```

**Step 2 :**

Past code in customer.xml in app/code/design/frontend/default/default/layout

```
<reference name="left">

<block type="customer/account_categories" name="customer_account_categories" template="customer/account/categories.phtml" />
</reference>
```

**Step 3 :** :

Last Create a phtml file in your template file(app/code/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/account) and past this code.

```
$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
   ->setLoadProductCount(true)
   ->setLoadProductCount(true)
   ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
   ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>true))
   ->load();
foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
  $_category->getName();
}
```

That's it get first level categories in your customer account navigation.

Answer (score 0):

create a block from back end, in that block call a phtml file as

{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/category_list.phtml"}}

Paste the following code in category_list.phtml file

`<?php 
    $_categories = Mage::getBlockSingleton(`catalog/navigation`);

```
    foreach ($_categories->getStoreCategories() as $_category) 
    { 
        $category = Mage::getModel(`catalog/category`); 
        $category->load($_category->getId()); 
        $subcategories = explode(`,`, $category->getChildren());
```

?>

```
    <dl> 
        <dt>`<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>`</dt> 
        <dd> 
            <ol> 
                <?php 
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategoryId)
                    { 
                        $category->load($subcategoryId); 
                            echo `<li><a href="` . $category->getURL() . `">` . $category->getName() . `</a></li>`; 
                    } 
                ?> 
            </ol> 
        </dd> 
    </dl>
```

Now call this block in customer.xml as follows:

`<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
       <block type="cms/block" name="my_block"><action method="setBlockId">     <block_id>my_block_id</block_id></action></block>
      </reference>
 </customer_account>`